# Does anyone know details of Satoshi Pay's decision to choose XLM over IOTA for their primary ledger technology?

Tags: untagged

> "Multiple ledger support will also allow us to use different ledgers
>   depending on the requirements of large corporate clients or industry
>   verticals of our nanopayment settlement platform. This is where our
>   long-term partnership with IOTA comes in. **While we didn’t pick IOTA
>   as the default ledger for our web content payment product**, we will
>   continue to evaluate IOTA for upcoming products, for example for
>   white-label solutions or in the Internet of things sector."

https://medium.com/@SatoshiPay/satoshipay-partners-with-stellar-org-4288ae0baa72

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the main reason is that IOTA is currently under heavy development and it can be that the network doesn't work. For example, when the IOTA developers asked every node provider to take it offline to install an update.

In summary, Satoshi Pay would have used IOTA if it would been production ready.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason is that XLM offered financial incentive in the form of a sizeable amount of XLM to satoshipay.